# take the latitude and longitude openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Good day people, I have a question, I am creating a map where I create two pointers (origin - Destination) where I can find the points depending on the address in the text box. As in several locations, the address is not defined what I want to do is take the latitude and longitude of the pointer when the user drags it. Until now I could only make the pointers move but I can not recover the latitude and longitude of them. I share the part of the code where I am doing that part.

```
//**** para mover el puntero Origen *****
var modifyOrigen = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: sourceOrigen});


   map.addInteraction(modifyOrigen);
   function addInteractions(e) {
   drawOrigen = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: sourceOrigen,
   type: iconoParadaCoche.value
  });

 map.addInteraction(draw);
 snapOrigen = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: sourceOrigen}); 
 map.addInteraction(snapOrigen);

}

 //**** para mover el puntero Destino *****
 var modifyDestino = new ol.interaction.Modify({source: 
 sourceDestino});
 map.addInteraction(modifyDestino);

 function addInteractions() {
  drawDestino = new ol.interaction.Draw({

    source: sourceDestino,
   type: iconoParadaCoche.value

  });
  map.addInteraction(drawDestino);
  snapDestino = new ol.interaction.Snap({source: sourceDestino});
   map.addInteraction(snapDestino);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to obtain the coordinates at the modifyend event

```
modifyOrigen.on('modifyend', function(evt) { 
  console.log(evt.features.item(0).getGeometry().getCoordinates());
});
```